# MS Graph permission added to Azure AD app registration breaks sign-in flow via Intune Company Portal app

Tags: azure-active-directory, adal, microsoft-graph-intune

I have created an Azure AD app registration for a cross-platform (Xamarin.Forms) mobile application for our employees. The app registration is setup to work as a single-tenant app and in order to function properly, we have specified a number of permissions to Microsoft Graph, such as "openid", "profile", and "User.Read", which have been given admin consent by our Admin. The app uses broker authentication (using ADAL) in order to sign-in users to the app via the Intune Company Portal app already installed and setup on every user's device.

Up until recently, everything worked fine until we needed to add a new Microsoft Graph permission to the app registration, namely "Group.Read.All". So, we added the new permission to our app registration as a delegated permission and had our admin provide the admin consent for all the users.

After giving consent to the new permission, our users could not login to the app since the Intune Company Portal app did not sign-in the users to the app, but instead advised them to setup their device by installing and setting up the Intune Company Portal app on their device (?!).

As I mentioned before, the devices **already** had Intune Company Portal installed and properly setup on their device for more than 2 years now.

So, we thought of checking the user sign-ins of the user to find out what the problem was and we found a failure event recorded with sign-in error code 530003 (Access has been blocked due to conditional access policies.) where it showed that the policy "**Access Policy: Require Device Enrollment for Accessing EOL & Sharepoint from handheld devices**" failed with reason "**require compliant device**" (under column Grant Controls).

**As soon as we revoked the newly added permission "Group.Read.All" from the app registration, our users could sign-in to the app successfully.**

When we tried adding other permissions like Directory.Read.All and GroupMember.Read.All, we did not have any issues with our sign-in flow via the Intune Company Portal.

Can you please advise what it is so special about the "Group.Read.All" permission that raises the Azure sign-in error code 530003, forcing the Intune Company Portal app to require the users to setup their (already setup) device, before they can sign-in to our app?

I am at my wits' end with this one.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

For me it is not possible to reproduce your issue due to multiple things involved.

Few suggestions that you could try at your end:

1. Try isolate each component and leverage graph explorer/postman to make an API call and observe behavior.
2. I didn't get the need to add graph permission, but as per your use case see if there is any other least privileged permission that could get your job done, add that permission and check behavior.
3. Check if your scenario really demanded adding permission as delegated and if this is really supported? For e.g, below image shows necessary permssion to get the properties and relationships of a group object.

[image]

4. If problem still persists, consider contacting Microsoft support for your specific scenario.